# Hikari connectionTimeout only when pool is full

Tags: java, hikaricp, apache-commons-dbcp

I am working on converting a application's database connection pooling from Apache's DBCP2 to Hikari.  So far everything is looking great except I've run into an issue with Hikari's `connectionTimeout` property. This is a web application with a fairly high volume of traffic and our preferred behavior is for an error to be thrown quickly if the pool is full so that a spike in a certain kind of traffic does not tie up all of our request handling threads waiting for a connection. We'd rather have these requests error as the vast majority of our traffic will be retried later if needed.

With DBCP2, we currently have the `maxWaitMillis` property set to 1 second. Hikari's `connectionTimeout` appears to be the equivalent of that so I tried setting that to 1 second as well.

However, when I do this I start getting “login timed out” SQLException. If I change `connectionTimeout` back to the default of 30 seconds the issue goes away.

Re-reading the documentation, there seems to be a subtle difference between these properties.

Hikari's `connectionTimeout`:

> This property controls the maximum number of milliseconds that a
>   client (that's you) will wait for a connection from the pool. If this
>   time is exceeded without a connection becoming available, a
>   SQLException will be thrown. Lowest acceptable connection timeout is
>   250 ms. Default: 30000 (30 seconds)

DBCP2’s `maxWaitMillis`:

> The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there
>   are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before
>   throwing an exception, or -1 to wait indefinitely.

It seems that in DBCP2 the `maxWaitMillis` timer only kicks in when you try to borrow a connection when the pool is full.  Hikari's `connectionTimeout` applies to any scenario when you borrow a connection which means that it also applies to the case where the pool is not full and a new connection must be opened.  In this case, opening a new connection is taking longer than 1 second which is why the SQLException is being thrown.

I prefer DBCP2's approach here. If I'm opening a new connection, take as long as needed. There is a finite number of connections available in the pool so at most `maximumPoolSize` number of threads could be waiting. However, if the pool is exhausted, I don't want threads to wait as there could an unbounded number of threads waiting to borrow a connection from the pool. These seems like very different cases that should allow for different timeouts.

Is there any way to achieve the behavior I'm looking for in Hikari?